# Hi why can SQL's union recognize two difference field?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Hi I saw the result of my code, it shows a row 'code' (as bolded)
but I do have another row of country_code, how did sql know they are the same?
or this is just a bug in datacamp's stimulator?

Thanks everyone for your knowledge!!!

```sql
-- Select fields
SELECT code, year
  -- From economies
  FROM economies
    -- Set theory clause
    union all
-- Select fields
SELECT country_code, year
  -- From populations
  FROM populations
-- Order by code, year
ORDER BY code, year;
```

Comment: The columns names in UNION are always taken from the most first subquery. Names/aliases from all another subqueries are ignored/unavailable/lost. You may access the subquery column only in this subquery, not in combined rowset (for example, for separate subquery ordering) - in this case the subquery must be enclosed with parenthesis.

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you want to do union of two select then your first select defines what the column name will be.

Comment: *but I do have another row of country_code, how did sql know they are the same?* UNION uses posessional matching. I.e. the posession of the column in the subquery output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query reproduced again:

```sql
SELECT code, year
FROM economies
UNION ALL
SELECT country_code, year    -- aliases here are ignored
FROM populations
ORDER BY code, year;
```

The aliases/column names which are specified in the *first* query in the union (of 2 or more queries) are what are used throughout the rest of the union query.  That is to say, in the `ORDER BY` clause, the aliases specified in the first portion of the union are what are available to use.